# How to solve connection not secure in selenium under windows 10 OS ? HELP SLENIUM firefox tests automation community pleease

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, firefox, windows-10, ssl-certificate

it's a super serious problem for me in my project. I googled, and tried myself, but nothing solved.... I m trying to execute automated tests on Firfox browser .... I m developping my tests using java and selenium on Windows 10 as my OS .. my automated tests can run under chrome with no problem but when I launch my tests on firefox it throws the browser opens but it throws an error "Unsecured connection (in frensh : La connexion n’est pas sécurisée ) ....

Down is my code and a screnn shot of firfpox browser throwing the error while trying to run tests

I launch my tests successivly as a group of tests gathered using jar,

here is my code as shown bellow with a screen shot of the thrown error :

Comment: oh sorry ! here s my code :  first part :  
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--incognito"));
   driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
  } 
  else if (Context.webDriverTarget.toString().toUpperCase().equals(WebBrowser.FIREFOX.toString())) {
   if (Context.pathToRessources == null) {
    ClassLoader classLoader = ExtentManager.class.getClassLoader();
    URL resourceAsStream = classLoader.getResource("geckodriver.exe");
    Path path = Paths.get(resourceAsStream.toURI());
    System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", path.toString());
   }

Comment: second part :  else {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", Context.pathToRessources + "\\" + "geckodriver.exe");
   }
   
   DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

Comment: third part (sorry for messy posting BUT it's such urgent ISSUE need this on my project to test our app on both chrome/firfox and IE 11 too) :   
   desiredCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
   desiredCapabilities.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
   desiredCapabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.MARIONETTE, false);

Comment: 4 th part :  desiredCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
   desiredCapabilities.setCapability("acceptInsecureCerts", true);
//   WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(desiredCapabilities);

   FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
   profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
   profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);

Comment: finally :  profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", context.getDataModel().getDownloadPath());
   profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "image/gif");

Comment: profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf");
   profile.setPreference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", true);
   profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);

Comment: profile.setPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);
   
   profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true) ;
//   profile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);
   
   FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions().setProfile(profile);
   driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
   driver.manage().window().maximize();
  }

Comment: PS : I'm using SELENIUM 3.5.3, FIREFOX 60.0.1, Java 8 and windows 10 (64 bits) Thank YOU! IN ADVANCED :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my ISSUE :) ... just in case , for the ones that may have this problem with Firefox #INSECURE CONNECTION error#

I'm working with :
OS :
    Windows 10 (64 bits)
Browser :
    Firefox v60.0.1 (32 bits)
And,
   SELENIUM 3.5.3

[merionette driver to gecko driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pE8Wm.png)

Solution (as shown in the image attached):
Instead of this -> System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", path.toString());
I used this -> System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", path.toString());

I hope it will help anyone who is facing the same problem
Thanks 
:)
Regards